# Handle Now button in Antd Datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want my datepicker now button to be on a specific timezone and not my local timezone upon clicking.

Date picker now button to set to another timezone

Comment: did you try this https://ant.design/components/date-picker#localization

Answer (score 1):

Use moment-timezone library to achieve this. In this example, I am using Tokyo's time

Here is sample code:

```js
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

// Set the timezone you want to use
const timezone = 'Asia/Tokyo';

// Get the current date and time in the specified timezone
const now = moment().tz(timezone);

// Define a handleNow function that sets the value of the Datepicker component to the current date and time in the specified timezone
function handleNow() {
  setValue(now);
}

// Render the Datepicker component with the handleNow function as the onNow prop
<DatePicker onNow={handleNow} />
```